# why does it keep giving me errors?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE Application 
(
    App_ID number(5),
    Child_Name varchar2(15) 
        CONSTRAINT pk_Application_App_ID PRIMARY KEY, 
    Child_Weight number(2) 
        CONSTRAINT df_Application_Child_Weight DEFAULT 10 
            CHECK (Child_Weight > 0), 
    Nursery_ID number(7) 
        CONSTRAINT fk_Application_Nursey_ID 
            FOREIGN KEY (Nursery_ID) REFERENCES Nursey(Nursery_ID),  
    Bdate date 
        CONSTRAINT Application_Bdate CHECK (Bdate > '01-jan-2016' AND Bdate < '01-jun-2019')
)
```

I keep getting an error

> Constraint specification not allowed here

or

> Name is already used by an existing object

Comment: I removed the [tag:mysql] tag. Your use of `varchar2` and other syntax makes it clear you are using Oracle database, not MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

That's a mess; you should properly format code to see what's going on. Consider something like this, instead:

```
SQL> create table nursey (nursery_id number(7) primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table application (
  2      app_id       number(5),
  3      child_name   varchar2(15),
  4      child_weight number(2) default 10,
  5      nursery_id   number(7),
  6      bdate        date,
  7      --
  8      constraint pk_application_app_id primary key (app_id),
  9      constraint df_application_child_weight check (child_weight > 0),
 10      constraint fk_application_nursey_id foreign key (nursery_id)
 11         references nursey ( nursery_id ),
 12      constraint application_bdate check (    bdate > date '2016-01-01'
 13                                          and bdate < date '2019-06-01')
 14  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: You can have constraints in the middle of the code; they are called inline constraints.

Comment: Hm, true, you can. I know they can be used "in the same line" as columns, and - if they are *outline*, I always put them to the end of the CREATE TABLE statement (like my example shows). I never put them in between two columns, that's real mess.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors:

- `DEFAULT 10` in the middle of a `CHECK` constraint.
- When specifying an inline foreign key constraint you do not need to use the keywords `FOREIGN KEY` or specify the column name.

You probably have a third error:

- You spelt `Nursery` as `Nursey`

It is also bad practice to compare dates with strings (even if the strings look like dates). Instead you should use date literals.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Application (
    App_ID       number(5),
    Child_Name   varchar2(15) 
                 CONSTRAINT pk_Application_App_ID PRIMARY KEY, 
    Child_Weight number(2) DEFAULT 10
                 CONSTRAINT df_Application_Child_Weight CHECK (Child_Weight > 0), 
    Nursery_ID   number(7) 
                 CONSTRAINT fk_Application_Nursey_ID REFERENCES Nursey(Nursery_ID),  
    Bdate        date 
                 CONSTRAINT Application_Bdate CHECK (Bdate > DATE '2016-01-01' AND Bdate < DATE '2019-07-01')
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=68132db5a64adf77f4a19c452330b993)*